# Does Notepad++ have a minimap feature?

Tags: notepad++

I'm not really sure what to call the "minimap" feature of a text editor.

For example, Sublime Text has what I would call a Minimap feature. A skinny map on the left side where you can click to get to different parts of the file.

[image: http://www.sublimetext.com/]

Seems like there would be a Notepad++ plugin for this.

Anybody know?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The new version of NP++ (6.0) has document map feature. Go `View->Document Map`. Document map or minimap will appear right hand side of the editor

Answer (score 4):

I am not aware of any plugin like that, but Notepad++ has a Function List plugin which lists your function on the side, which helps with navigation a little. Google *"Notepad++ function list plugin"* for information

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/

Answer (score 1):

If you use only one of Notepad++'s 2 frames (views) at a time, you use this hack:

1. Make the splitter between the frames vertical (if horizontal, right-click on the splitter and select *Rotate to Left*).
2. Right-click the tab of the file you wish to edit and select *Clone to other view*.
3. Click the view you wish to make the minimap and do Ctrl + Mousewheel-down until the font size is as small as possible/desired.
4. Check View > Synchronize Vertical Scrolling and optionally View > Synchronize Horizontal Scrolling.

Now scrolling either the "minimap" or normal view scrolls the other. Sadly, text selections are not replicated.

Comment: You sure you don't mean "Synchronize Vertical Scrolling"?

Comment: @Oliver: You may want to synchronize horizontal scrolling as well if you have long lines.