# Does notepad++ have the quick scroll pane that Sublime Text have?

Tags: notepad++, sublime-text

[Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) ([Download](http://www.sublimetext.com/2)) has the following feature that I use it all the time:

[image]

I would like to know if [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) ([Download](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/)) have this feature. I call this feature 'Quick Scroll Pane' as I do not know the exact name for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Does notepad++ have a quick scroll pane?

Notepad++ does have this feature, it is called [Document Map](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/document-map.html).

You can enable it from the menu using "View" > "Document Map" or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>,<kbd>D</kbd>.

[image: Document map screenshot]

Source [Using Document Map in Notepad++](http://code2care.org/pages/using-document-map-in-notepadplusplus/)

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to reduce the text size in the Document Map? Sublime fits more lines in the same height.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun the document map font size seems to be related to the main window font size (when I control mousewheel in the main window the document map font size changes as well).

Answer (score 8):

In Sublime Text it's called Minimap, in Notepad++ [Document Map](https://superuser.com/a/405324) (go to `View > Document Map`)

Comment: I think you should flag this as a duplicate instead of answering. You even have a link there and SublimeText is also mentioned in the other question...

Comment: This question have more links that the one mentioned in other question. :)